# How Can I reduce speed of one player and increase speed of another player when it comes closer to one another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Here, in my code using Microsoft visual studio in C# for game development to detect Collision. I wrote the script to find shortest path of the player using the A* algorithm. In this script, I am unable to detect collision between different players.I want to reduce the speed of one player and increase the speed of another player using different tags. But I am unable to handle the speed of the player.

Here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
public class PathfindingTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The A* manager.
    private AStarManager AStarManager = new AStarManager();
    // Array of possible waypoints.
    List<GameObject> Waypoints = new List<GameObject>();
    // Array of waypoint map connections. Represents a path.
    List<Connection> ConnectionArray = new List<Connection>();
    // The start and end target point.
    public GameObject start;
    public GameObject end;
    // Debug line offset.
    Vector3 OffSet = new Vector3(0, 0.3f, 0);
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    private Transform target;
    int current;
    //float WPradius = 0.5f;
    Connection aConnection;
    public Text countText;
    private int countit;
    //public GameObject[] targets;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (start == null || end == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("No start or end waypoints.");
            return;
        }

        // Find all the waypoints in the level.
        GameObject[] GameObjectsWithWaypointTag;
        GameObjectsWithWaypointTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");

        foreach (GameObject waypoint in GameObjectsWithWaypointTag)
        {
            WaypointCON tmpWaypointCon = waypoint.GetComponent<WaypointCON>();
            if (tmpWaypointCon)
            {
                Waypoints.Add(waypoint);
            }
        }

        // Go through the waypoints and create connections.
        foreach (GameObject waypoint in Waypoints)
        {
            WaypointCON tmpWaypointCon = waypoint.GetComponent<WaypointCON>();
            // Loop through a waypoints connections.
            foreach (GameObject WaypointConNode in tmpWaypointCon.Connections)
            {
                Connection aConnection = new Connection();
                aConnection.SetFromNode(waypoint);
                aConnection.SetToNode(WaypointConNode);
                AStarManager.AddConnection(aConnection);
            }
        }

        // Run A Star...
        ConnectionArray = AStarManager.PathfindAStar(start, end);
        //  Debug.Log(ConnectionArray.Count);
        // rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //rb.MovePosition((ConnectionArray[0].GetFromNode().transform.position + OffSet));
        //transform.position = ConnectionArray[0].GetFromNode().transform.position;
        countit = 0;
        countText.text = "Count: " + countit;
        /*countTextTwo.text = "Counttwo:" + countit;
        countTextThree.text = "Countthree:" + countit;*/
    }

    // Draws debug objects in the editor and during editor play (if option set).
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        // Draw path.
        foreach (Connection aConnection in ConnectionArray)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawLine((aConnection.GetFromNode().transform.position + OffSet),
             (aConnection.GetToNode().transform.position + OffSet));
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position != ConnectionArray[current].GetToNode().transform.position)
        {
            Vector3 pos2 = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetToNode().transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            var LookPos = ConnectionArray[current].GetToNode().transform.position - transform.position;
            LookPos.y = 0;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(LookPos), 1);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(pos2);
            //Debug.Log(transform.position);
        }
        else
        {
            current = (current + 1) % ((ConnectionArray.Count));
            // if (current + 2 == (ConnectionArray.Count - 1) && (transform.position != ConnectionArray[current].GetToNode().transform.position))
            if (current + (ConnectionArray.Count - 1) == (ConnectionArray.Count - 1) && (transform.position != ConnectionArray[current].GetToNode().transform.position))
            {
                if ((transform.position != ConnectionArray[(current + (ConnectionArray.Count - 1))].GetFromNode().transform.position))
                {
                    countit = countit + 1;
                    countText.text = "Count:" + countit;
                    /*countTextTwo.text = "Counttwo:" + countit;
                    countTextThree.text = "Countthree:" + countit;*/
                    speed = speed - 1 f;
                }
                ConnectionArray.Reverse();
                Vector3 pos3 = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(pos3);
                if (countit == 10)
                {
                    speed = 0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                {
                    current = (current) % ((ConnectionArray.Count));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("target"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            countit = countit + 1;
            countText.text = "Count: " + countit;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playerfirstspeed"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playersecondspeed"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playerthirdspeed"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("target"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playerfirstspeed"))
        {
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed - 2);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playersecondspeed"))
        {
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed - 2);
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("playerthirdspeed"))
        {
            Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, ConnectionArray[current].GetFromNode().transform.position, speed - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you pick who gets to speed up and who gets to slow down?

Comment: This is the problem... I was unable to solve this

Comment: Well this is a design issue - you need to work out how you are going to decide who slows and who speeds, none of us should decide that for you

Comment: Is all your code relevant for this question? It is a bit much and in the current formatting very hard to parse

Comment: @derHugo Do you have any idea? If one player comes closer to another then first will change its direction?

Comment: @SunilGhimire as comments before: Define `first`! From the code perspective there is only two players coming closer .. how do you define who is first?

Comment: I have three players in my unity3d and this script is attached to each player with their start point and endpoint lastly speed is added statically i.e. speed for the first player = 30, second player = 30 and third player = 50. And the main aim is to find shortest path I don't want to collide player with each other.

Answer (score 0):

As im understand u have only one variable "speed" for all of three players.

Hows about to declare "speed" variable for each player, then check certain raduis for collisions with other players, get other players by collision and make addition or substraction for them?

Comment: I have declared the same speed (float) variable for all players. My aim for this script to detect collision which means I want to reduce the speed of one player and increase speed of another player. I dont want to make collision of any player.

Comment: This will return all colliders within radius. From there you can access gameObject.
     *Transform [] array;
     void GetInactiveInRadius(){
        foreach (Transform tr in array){
          float distanceSqr = (transfor.position - tr.position).sqrMagnitude;
          if(distanceSqr < rangeSqr)
           //setSpeed of other player
        }
     }*
Add flag, if anything in radius, then reduce speed of current player, and add speed to other players.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Comment: Do you have any idea for player back movement if another player comes closer ?